# What is the process for changing auto-generated messages to help new users feel more welcome and understand how to better use the site?

Tags: support, feature-request, new-users

I was discussing this issue with a moderator, @SteveTaylor, and he suggested bringing it up here. Sometimes questions get marked as a possible duplicate and they get closed before the OP has a chance to explain how their question is different from others that seem to be similar. New users may not be aware that their question can be closed if not corrected based on votes by community members. I suggested the following blurb as a gentler way to inform new users of how the site functions.

> This question has been marked as a possible duplicate. Please show how
> your question differs from those already asked or it could be closed
> based on votes by the community.

What is the procedure for evaluating and instituting such a change?

Comment: This isn't something the mods can change, it would have to be changed by SE staff. So the procedure is probably to go to [meta.se] and write a convincing feature request post.

Comment: Okay, @curiousdannii, thanks for that info.

Comment: They sent me back here with this message.      " The Main-Meta post here explains:

This is already possible - just not by mods or normal users.

If you need one, just post a feature-request on your meta site with the proposed wording and why you think you need it.

If the consensus is favourable, a site-mod may then contact a staff member to effect the change.

A recent example in-progress is on Worldbuilding here."